# Which is correct tense to be used with last year?

Tags: sentence-construction, past-perfect

Which sentence is correct ?

> a) Last year, Court had convicted him for murder.
>
> b) Last year, Court convicted him for murder.

I have received answers that Both of my sentence constructions are correct and can be used as per context. But I have learned that perfect tense can not be use with timeline in this example it is Last year.

I am sharing below links to support this

https://www.englishgrammar.org/common-mistakes-verbs/

https://www.englishgrammar.org/correct-sentences/

Comment: I have received answers that both are correct and can be used as per context. But What about time lines i.e. Last year. I have learned that Time line can be use while construing Perfect tense.

Comment: I was curious, so I came back to see that 1. **You have not accepted** any answer (Present Perfect) 2. **You did not award** the bounty. (Simple Past) Then I looked at your active page and saw  3. **you rarely upvote** anyone's contributions (Present Simple). **I had answered** (Past Perfect) because I thought the question was rather good and I saw I could add something new. In any case, I hope the words in bold show when the Past Perfect can be used.

Answer (score 7):

In sentence a, **had convicted** is past perfect: you only used this to talk about something that happened **before** some event in the past.

> The police **had** cautioned him several times **before** the court convicted him of murder.

In sentence b, **convicted** is simple past: this is used to talk about something that happened before now.

Sentence b is the right one to use in this example because there is no other event in the past. Note that in the UK it would be normal to put the definite article before **court**, and the correct preposition to use for **convict** is **of**:

> Last year the court convicted him of murder.

Comment: "The court" is correct in the U.S., also.

Answer (score 7):

As is often the case with the choice of past tenses, both are perfectly grammatical and idiomatic (as regards the tense. There are other issues which are not quite idiomatic: see JavaLatte's answer), and both could be used to refer to exactly the same set of events.

The difference lies in how the speaker is choosing to relate the events, and (in particular) the temporal sequence.

If you use the first form *Last year, the Court had convicted him for murder*, you are saying that the temporal focus is at some time in the past, but later than the conviction. In a narrative, this will mean either that the story time has already been established at this later time, or this sentence itself will establish a story time for subsequent sentences.

If you use the second form, you are not setting a story time: the narrative might continue from the conviction, or from the present, or from some time in between.

Comment: In other words, "had convicted" is acceptable in a sentence that discusses something that happens later than the conviction. Since the quoted sentences do not mention any later event, as a reader I am left with a feeling that something is missing from the sentence... So I would say a) is incorrect.

Comment: @laugh Not at all. It happens all the time in conversation, that one might use **had** in a sentence like that. Yes, it depends on context but is not incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

None of the sentences by the OP are "correct" for several reasons.

1. As JavaLatte's answer explains, the definite article, the, is required before *court*, and I don't see any justification for capitalising it either. The word *court* is not a proper noun and unless the actual tribunal building is called "Court", it should not have a capital letter. Thus if we operate the necessary changes we are left with this

> - (a) Last year, **the** **c**ourt had convicted him for murder.
> - (b) Last year, **the c**ourt convicted him for murder.

2. Next, the biggest obstacle in my view is not which tense is used but the preposition "for". Again, this is also mentioned in [JavaLatte's answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/154315/1694).

Prepositions are awkward little words, sometimes more that one preposition can fit but carry a different nuance in meaning, e.g. *think about* and *think of*, other times there is no difference in meaning but much depends on your dialect, e.g. *at the weekend* and *on the weekend*. But in the case of *[convict](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/convict)* the preposition used by native speakers is, without doubt, **of**. This [website](https://lingohelp.me/preposition-after-adjective/convicted-of-for-by-in/) claims that **convicted of** is used 91% of the times whereas **convicted for** is only used in 5% of the cases.

### With The Grammar Fixed…

> - (a) Last year, the court had convicted him **of** murder. [PAST PERFECT]
> - (b) Last year, the court convicted him **of** murder. [SIMPLE PAST]

Now, both sentences are grammatical and respect the norms of spelling and punctuation. This is where I differ from JavaLatte's answer and I agree with [Colin Fine's](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/154316/1694). Without further context, it is not possible to say which sentence is *preferable*, a bare sentence, as long as it is grammatical cannot be "wrong".

### The Present Perfect

3. The OP believes that a *timeline* cannot be used with the perfect aspect. That is not entirely accurate. **It is the Present Perfect that is not normally used with an expression of time**

> - (c) WRONG: Last year, the court **has convicted** him of murder

The sentence is in nonstandard English or ungrammatical (depending on one's point of view), the Present Perfect is used when our focus is not on the *time* the action occurred; e.g., “The court has convicted him” and when the speaker is more interested in the results felt in the *present* e.g. the assassin has been found guilty of murder and will be sentenced. He cannot harm anyone now.

> - (c) CORRECT: The court ***has convicted*** him of murder. (Now, he is in jail) [PRESENT PERFECT]